# Receiving JSON (Cosmos DB Documents) as input from Azure Service Bus in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-functions-runtime

I have an Azure Function (f1) take Cosmos DB Documents as input and I want to set up a path to redirect any Documents to an Azure Service Bus Queue in case of some kind of failure that might happen downstream (SQL statement to a SQL Server) possibly. I want to then run an Azure Function (f2) on a timer that will serve as "cleanup" for any of these redirected documents and attempt to do the same thing basically that f1 tried to do.

I have been able to send a single Document or multiple documents to a ServiceBus Queue but I could only successfully process input from a Queue in f2 when it was a single Document. Note that f2 is on a trigger and I am still not sure how to even read a queue from an Azure function?  How would I accomplish iterating through the entire Queue of messages in 1 function? The bindings show that ServiceBus is not a valid "Input" for Azure Functions though it is valid as a trigger. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings

What I am working with below so far:

f1 with a single output

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public static void Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> inputFeed, TraceWriter log,
    out Document outputSbQueue)
{
  //f1 with a single output to a Queue
}
```

f1 with an ICollector output

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public static void Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> inputFeed, TraceWriter log,
    ICollector<Document> outputSbQueue)
{
  //f1 with an ICollector output
}
```

f2 with a single input from a ServiceBus trigger (works)

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public static void Run(Document myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    //f2 with a working single input -- myQueueItem is an SB trigger
}
```

f2 with an ICollector or any kind of IEnumerable input (doesn't work...throws Exception about JSon serialization at runtime)

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static void Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    //f2 with an input of more than one document
}
```

throws this exception:

> 2018-05-15T20:48:21.535 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myQueueItem'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Binding parameters to complex objects (such as 'ICollector`1') uses Json.NET serialization. 
>   1. Bind the parameter type as 'string' instead of 'ICollector`1' to get the raw values and avoid JSON deserialization, or
>   2. Change the queue payload to be valid json. The JSON parser failed: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ICollector`1[Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.

I am a complete newb to dealing with JSON, serialization and deserialization. I just want to parse it, read stuff from it and get a SQL statement ready to send downstream.

Comment: Your two versions of `f2` seem exactly the same. Please reduce the question to a minimum possible reproduction scenario, no need to describe your whole app.

Comment: You're right of course! Sorry I hadn't realized the error when I initially formed. I corrected it to illustrate my question in the second version of f2. Thank you for the catch

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Service Bus Trigger doesn't support batches (multiple items as input). See [Service Bus Batch Trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1024) github issue.

If I understand your scenario correctly, you don't necessarily have to accept a batch in `f2` function, nor do you need to "iterate through the entire Queue of messages".

Iteration will be handled by Functions. Your `f2` function will get called as many times as many messages `f1` sends to the Service Bus queue. If you "clean up" the documents one-by-one as you get them, you will eventually clean up all of the documents.

Comment: correct. I just have to try or re-try enough times on a timer but if it is on a trigger and there is still currently a downstream problem then it doesn't do much for me as it would re-try at the same time nearly as the failure occurred.

Comment: @kyarbles One workaround could be to schedule Service Bus messages in the future by using `BrokeredMessage` for output binding and setting `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` on it

Comment: I see. I'll look into it. I might also try using something like Azure Blob or Table storage or something that is a valid input into the function. Thanks!